# Created an image element in xaml, how to load on button press?

Tags: c++, xaml

Hi I am creating a windows 8 app with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and I have created a button and an image element in xaml. What I would like is to press the button and load an image. At first just any image. Here is my xaml

> `<Button Name="drawButton" Content="Draw" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="427,204,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="drawButton_Click"/>`
>
> `<Image Name="card1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="96" Margin="684,204,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" Source=""/>`

and my c++ (I assume this is the error):

> `card1->Source = "cards//c1.png";`

any ideas? This shouldn't be rocket surgery....